# Why do questions no longer show who voted to migrate?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, migrated-questions

When a question was migrated from one site to another, it was possible to click the name of the origin site, and see the original question (or do so by adding `?noredirect=1` to the URL) and view a post notice showing that the post was migrated and who voted to migrate it.

This notice no longer shows the names of the users who voted to migrate. It did do so yesterday. An [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299817/use-vpn-to-prevent-setting-port-fowarding-in-router?noredirect=1) appears thus:

[image: migrated to serverfault.com ... by whom?]

These notices used to show the list of users (or worse, moderators) who voted to close or migrate the question.

I don't see this on [the list of recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/189912). In fact, it seems I can only find the list of users who voted by (being a moderator and) checking the post timeline, or looking at the post revision history. Is this a bug or does SE intend to stop showing who voted to close?

Comment: I guess the answer may very well be: "If you're interested in knowing this, it's one click away". The majority of people may not be interested in knowing immediately who voted for migration, since the source will eventually be removed from the migrated site.

Comment: If the post hasn't been edited at least once, then there's no one-click access to its revision history.

Comment: I think you can always view the "revision" page by visiting `http://<site>.com/posts/<post-id>/revisions`

Comment: Looking at the revision history on SO, I'm wondering if it is because it was a mod migration.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Nope, it happens with community migrated posts as well, such as [this one](http://superuser.com/posts/667512/revisions).

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok then, that blows my theory out of the water.

Comment: Because the imps who sort out the electrons went on lunch break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Who votes to migrate isn't always shown (when something is migrated to a site, in particular).  I'd removed the logic for displaying users as I'd misread it as *never* applying to the migration notice, instead of only applying sometimes.

Comment: As I understand it, the users who voted are displayed on the _origin_ site, and the time of the migration is displayed on the _destination_ site. Is this right?

Comment: @MichaelHampton That is correct.